# How to have a single tap "App info" shortcut from Recents screen?

Tags: 8.1-oreo

I'm looking for a way to launch App info of an app when its icon is clicked in Recents (Overview) screen. So far, my search has resulted in nothing fruitful.

I'm aware that Gravitybox prior to version for Nougat used to have this feature, but I'm on Android 8.1<sup><sup>1</sup></sup> and corresponding GravityBox [O] doesn't have such feature anymore. I also looked into InstallerOpt Xposed module, but to no avail.

I'm **aware of long-pressing the icon there followed by tapping the info icon in the right** but that requires two extra steps which reduces productivity with phone.

Edit: for the sake of clarity here: I'm aware of long-pressing on an icon in app drawer to get App Info option, but that is neither a single tap solution, nor is productive for me.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG: Overview screen]

---

<sup>1: On a rooted OnePlus 6 running stock ROM with Xposed Framework and Magisk.</sup>

Comment: Xbridge module had this feature but sadly it broke after Android 7 and was never updated